# Windows + Arch with 2 EFI partitions: Boot select only discovers windows

Tags: linux, windows-7, boot, partitioning, arch-linux

## Prior information

I wish to install Arch-Linux in a dual-boot configuration with windows 10. I have partitioned one singular drive into 7 partitions [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY9qL.png). I wish to enter into GRUB going where I can choose to boot windows or arch. I have followed the [Arch installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide) to the best of my ability but when I enter into boot select Arch does not show up. I have attempted this twice now doing the exact steps of:

1. Call `reboot` command from Archiso
2. Repeatedly press <kbd>F2</kbd> (Asus based motherboard: this is what it prompted).
3. Boot to that that looks to be the Arch installation (labelled Samsung 970 evo, same as windows). It prompting me with an 'installer screen'
4. `reboot` again
5. Enter windows 10
6. Nothing

## Problem in concrete words.

I wish to dual-boot with 2 EFIs, this does not work. Can I mark an EFI as bootable or primary? If so should I disable Window's EFI's 'primaryness'?

Comment: Did you figure this out?